# Php - Paypal v2 checkout orders returned status 422 when passing tax amount

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using [Standard PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/)

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script>

  paypal.Buttons({

   createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
     "purchase_units": [{
        "amount": {
          "currency_code": "AUD",
          "value": "273.9",
          "breakdown": {
            "item_total": {  /* Required when including the `items` array */
              "currency_code": "AUD",
              "value": "249",
              "tax": {
                "value": "24.9",
                "currency_code": "AUD"
               },
            }
          }
        },
        
         "shipping": {
           "name": {
           "full_name": "TestBuyer"
           },
          "address": {
            "addline_1": "1234 Main St",
            "area_2": "New San Jose",
            "area_1": "CA",
            "poscode": "9513",
            "cou_code": "AT"
         }
      },  

        "items": [
          {
            "name": "First Product Name", 
            "description": "Optional descriptive text..",
            "unit_amount": {
              "currency_code": "AUD",
              "value": "249"
            },
            "tax": {
                "value": "24.9",
                "currency_code": "AUD"
               },
            "quantity": "1"
          },   
        ]
      }]
  });
},


    // Finalize the transaction after payer approval

    onApprove: (data, actions) => {

      return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {

        // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:

        console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

        const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];

        alert(`Transaction ${transaction.status}: ${transaction.id}\n\nSee console for all available details`);

        // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:

        // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');

        // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';

        // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');

      });

    }

  }).render('#paypal-button-container');

</script>
```

I need tax value in above : like :

```
Sub-total  $249
Tax        $24.9
Total      $273.9
```

I added tax field in above but its giving me below error message :

> Error: /v2/checkout/orders returned status 422 (Corr ID:
> 86fc10bc7f8cc).
> {"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"field":"/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount/breakdown/item_total/value","value":"273.9","issue":"ITEM_TOTAL_MISMATCH","description":"Should
> equal sum of (unit_amount * quantity) across all items for a given
> purchase_unit"}],"message":"The requested action could not be
> performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business
> validation.","debug_id":"86fc10bc7f8cc","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-ITEM_TOTAL_MISMATCH","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}

Comment: any reason for close and minus vote , please comment to - so i can get idea what is mistake in asking such questions

Comment: The error message tells you the problem: the time total does not match, and “should equal sum of (unit_amount * quantity) across all items for a given purchase_unit”.

Comment: please see i have corrected value , actually mistype

Comment: i just need tax value , i am not getting where to but that tax field , if i remove tax value then  i get working process , only adding tax creating error, let me know , where i have to put tax fields

Comment: i means if i remove that "tax" array and used another name/value array in items , then its works , but that will be shown as product item , i need properly as tax

Comment: Not sure , tax array i have putted is right or wrong, can any one suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `breakdown` object needs a `tax_total`. Together with the `item_total` it should sum to the value in `amount`.

See the [v2 Orders API reference for amount breakdown.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-amount_breakdown)

```json
{
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "AUD",
        "value": "273.9",
        "breakdown": {
          "item_total": {
            "currency_code": "AUD",
            "value": "249"
          },
          "tax_total": {
            "value": "24.9",
            "currency_code": "AUD"
          }
        }
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "First Product Name",
          "description": "Optional descriptive text..",
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "AUD",
            "value": "249"
          },
          "tax": {
            "value": "24.9",
            "currency_code": "AUD"
          },
          "quantity": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i did : breakdown object  : "tax_total": { "value":"24.9", "currency_code": "AUD"}, still same error

Comment: Together with the item_total it must sum to the value in amount.

Comment: please can answer with some demo , i am not getting

Comment: Added JSON.....

Comment: yes it working , i just copy whole code of u r and its working , i have to look my side , thanks

Comment: i have seen many of your posts -  you have mention " Yes, use the JS SDK for payer approval instead of redirecting. But create and capture the order on the server via API if the result needs to be recorded in a database. So, the secret will also be used. "   -- so now i am working on sending data in my database via ajax post - can u please help me how to capture order on server via api , i have seen the link which u gave .. but not getting , i think most of the people would not getting same but don't ask , i am asking on behalf of many .. pls

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server is the most important link, that shows everything about the client-side of an integration including the fetch calls (which are like ajax) to two server endpoints. Implementing those server endpoints to call the v2/checkout/orders API and return JSON data (of order creation and capture) can be done with any backend, in any server-side language.

Comment: The main guide, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ , has a full stack example of a backend in node.js in particular, but of course that can be done in PHP or anything

Comment: thanks , just one thing in full stack example : 
 createOrder: (data, actions) => {
          return fetch("/api/orders", {
            method: "post",
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((order) => order.id);
        },  .. just want to know " api/orders " how its coming ? , do we need to call its via vendor or its coming default from script link ? and same "  return fetch(`/api/orders/${data.orderID}/capture`, {  " .. confusion here i am getting .. sorry i am week in namespace , vendor format

Comment: `/api/orders` is just an example path for one of the 2 routes you need to make, this is something you create on your website.  So it will be e.g. `www.yourserver.com/api/orders` .  The JS will fetch that path when it needs to create and capture an order respectively.  So what the server code at that path needs to do is in turn call the PayPal v2/checkout/orders API, and forward it back as a response (or do more with it before forwarding back, but capture errors need to be propagated back in a form the client JS code understands and can handle.)

Comment: Writing to a database -- that thing you want to do which makes a server integration the most appropriate solution -- can happen in the capture route right before forwarding the response JSON

Comment: thanks will look into , as i have deadline , will see